# Texts on the Generalized Method of Moments

Tags: reference-request, parameter-estimation

I was looking for a book that could explain me well the Generalized Method of Moments, its mathematical nuances, and even have a look to the empirical side, maybe with some guided exercises with Stata or another software package. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could have a look at [Cochrane's Asset Pricing book](http://press.princeton.edu/TOCs/c7099.html), chapter 11. It doesn't answer all your questions but it's a start I think.

Comment: Another good one is the book "time series analysis" by Hamilton